# Get invalid blocksize error when trying to generate a render base with osm2pgsql

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I'm trying to generate a database with the [osm2pgsql](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) schema using the ***osm2pgsql*** application, with the command:

```bash
osm2pgsql -H host -U user -P 5433  -W -d db -k -l -c -s file.pbf
```

But when I'm running osm2pgsql, I get the following error:

```
Using built-in tag processing pipeline
Using projection SRS 4326 (Latlong)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
Setting up table: planet_osm_line
Setting up table: planet_osm_polygon
Setting up table: planet_osm_roads
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Allocating memory for sparse node cache
Sharing dense sparse
Node-cache: cache=800MB, maxblocks=102400*8192, allocation method=11
Mid: pgsql, scale=10000000 cache=800
Setting up table: planet_osm_nodes
Setting up table: planet_osm_ways
Setting up table: planet_osm_rels
Reading in file: snapdb.pbf
Invalid blocksize 1010792557
Error occurred, cleaning up
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at the [osm2pgsql](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) [source code](https://trac.openstreetmap.org/browser/subversion/applications/utils/export/osm2pgsql-64/parse-pbf.c?rev=26020) and the error  `Invalid blocksize %lu`  occurs when the osm2pgsql verifies the header size of the file, so I presumed that this error is with my `.pbf` file.

My problem was when I created my `.pfb` file using the [osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis)  application, I created a `.osm` file with the `.pbf` extension using this command:

```
osmosis --read-apidb host="host" database="db" user="user" password="pass" --write-xml file="test.pbf"
```

**I did this using the argument `--write-xml` instead of `--write-pbf`.**

So, when I was running the ***osm2pgsql***:

```
osm2pgsql -H host -U user -P 5433  -W -d db -k -l -c -s file.pbf
```

The tool was getting the extension by the file's name and trying to read the `.osm`  file as a `.pbf` file. **Is it a bug?**

---

I solved this problem simply by renaming my file to `.osm` using:

```
mv file.pbf file.osm
```

Or I could create the file again using the correct command:

```
osmosis --read-apidb host="host" database="db" user="user" password="pass" --write-pbf file="test.pbf"
```